# How to display a jinja2 template once the progress bar is 100% complete

Tags: python, flask, progress-bar

I have configured an application in Flask that aims to display a progress bar. The idea is that the progress bar is displayed while the app.py validates the login credentials.

The progress bar is displayed as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

What I want is that when the progress bar reaches 100% the control is passed to the template 'dashboard.html'. The 'dashboard.html' includes menu options as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

From all the examples I have researched on progress bar; show how to display a progress bar.
However, they do not demonstrate how to direct the control to another @ app.route of an app once the progress bar has completed 100%.

I have reviewed the example provided in the following link: [Flask Application that has a progress bar using EventSource](https://github.com/djdmorrison/flask-progress-example)  (https://github.com/djdmorrison/flask-progress-example) however I have no clue where to include the instructions that display the template 'dashboard.html' once the progress bar is 100% complete.

Attached is the source code and the jinja2 templates of the app.py written in Flask:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/progress')
def progress():

    def generate():
        x = 0
    
        while x <= 100:

            yield "data:" + str(x) + "\n\n"
            x = x + 10
            time.sleep(0.5)

    return Response(generate(), mimetype= 'text/event-stream')

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var source = new EventSource("/progress");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', event.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);
        $('.progress-bar-label').text(event.data+'%');

        if(event.data == 100){
            source.close()
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="text-center container">
        <h1>Login page</h1>
        <p>Login will take some time as the system needs to validate your credentials. Once the progress bar reaches 100% you will be able to access the Dashboard. Thanks for waiting.</p>

        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <span class="progress-bar-label"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dashboard.html</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Option 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Option 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Option 4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Option 5</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any guidance to achieve the purpose would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

**Solution:** Following @janpeterka's recommendation - I have updated the version of index.html in case it is useful for those interested in how to direct the call to another route once the progress bar reaches 100%.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var source = new EventSource("/progress");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', event.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);
        $('.progress-bar-label').text(event.data+'%');

        if(event.data == 100){
            source.close()
            /* redirect to dashboard.html after progress bar finishes */
            window.location.replace(window.location.pathname.split("/")[0] + "/dashboard");
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="text-center container">
        <h1>Login page</h1>
        <p>Login will take some time as the system needs to validate your credentials. Once the progress bar reaches 100% you will be able to access the Dashboard. Thanks for waiting.</p>

        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <span class="progress-bar-label"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Next I attach the log file of the execution of app.py where it is observed how the redirection to the "/dashboard" route displays the status 200. Everything works perfectly.

```
$ python app.py
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2021 08:52:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2021 08:52:06] "GET /progress HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2021 08:52:11] "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Maybe you can redirect after progress bar finishes with something like `window.location.replace(window.location.pathname.split("/")[0] + "/dashboard);`

Comment: @ janpeterka- Perfect. Thanks a lot!. I have updated the source code in the index.html template following your suggestion. I have updated the version of index.html in case it is useful for those interested in how to direct the call to another route once the progress bar reaches 100%.